# Setting Alsa to output 44.1kHz

Tags: audio, configuration, alsa

I would like Alsa to output everything at 44.1kHz (by default it looks like it's using 48kHz). I understand that the correct option would be something like:

```
defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 44100
```

But where should this be included: in `.asoundrc` or `.asoundrc.asoundconf`? Does `.asoundrc` override settings in `.asoundrc.asoundconf`?

Comment: Some hardware might not support 44.1 kHz.

Comment: Hmm, isn't 44.1 kHz the *most* widely supported standard in soundcard hardware?

Comment: No, 44.1 kHz exists only because of audio CDs. The most widely supported standard is 48 kHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible locations for the configuration file are `/etc/asound.conf` for all users, or `~/.asoundrc` for a single user.

The file `~/.asoundrc.asoundconf` is a file created by the `asoundconf` tool, and should not be edited by hand.

Comment: So if `.asoundrc` contains `defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 44100`, and `.asoundrc.asoundconf` contains `defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 48000`, then Alsa will be outputting 44.1 kHz?